# curl long url with query parameters

Tags: bash, curl, instagram

I am trying to curl a long URL like the following and save it into a file:

https://instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=gKuf2i9Vj5MAX-prxmR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjgxMDI0MDUzNDIyMTEzNzMyOQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT9BhJfQrBULLiNNXWfLQjhog3T8szmLRvMUEfWqE-cQIQ&oe=6266DFF7&_nc_sid=83d603

where the filename should be only `277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg`

`curl "https://instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=gKuf2i9Vj5MAX-prxmR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjgxMDI0MDUzNDIyMTEzNzMyOQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT9BhJfQrBULLiNNXWfLQjhog3T8szmLRvMUEfWqE-cQIQ&oe=6266DFF7&_nc_sid=83d603"` doesnt save it to a file

Comment: You haven't described the problem fully. You should explain what message curl reports. Looking at it, I can't tell if your problem is a) missing quotes, b) you specified `-o` instead of `-O`, or if c) you _are_ using `-O` and appropriate quotes and have discovered that it attempts to include the whole query string in the filename.

Comment: I removed the `jq` tag as it seemed irrelevant to the question you were asking, but I realise now you may have been asking for a solution using `jq`? If so feel free to edit it back in but I think you need to be more clear about how it is relevant in the body of the question.

Comment: @Weeble fixed the curl example sorry, it prints the image to to the console but i want it to be saved as a file under the original image name ie `277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you have tried the `-o` and `-O` options, but they don't seem to do what you want.

```
$ curl -o 'https://instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=gKuf2i9Vj5MAX-prxmR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjgxMDI0MDUzNDIyMTEzNzMyOQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT9BhJfQrBULLiNNXWfLQjhog3T8szmLRvMUEfWqE-cQIQ&oe=6266DFF7&_nc_sid=83d603'
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

This fails because `-o` requires you to specify the filename yourself. The correct way to use `-o` is to specify the filename yourself:

```
$ curl -o '277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg' 'https://instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=gKuf2i9Vj5MAX-prxmR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjgxMDI0MDUzNDIyMTEzNzMyOQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT9BhJfQrBULLiNNXWfLQjhog3T8szmLRvMUEfWqE-cQIQ&oe=6266DFF7&_nc_sid=83d603'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  175k  100  175k    0     0  85047      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 85527
```

You haven't really explained why this isn't satisfactory, so I'll assume that you are getting the URL from user input or a file or something.

This is what the `-O` option is for. But it turns up another problem:

```
$ curl -O 'https://instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=gKuf2i9Vj5MAX-prxmR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjgxMDI0MDUzNDIyMTEzNzMyOQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT9BhJfQrBULLiNNXWfLQjhog3T8szmLRvMUEfWqE-cQIQ&oe=6266DFF7&_nc_sid=83d603'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: 277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_n
Warning: c_ht=instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=gKuf2i9Vj5MAX
Warning: -prxmR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjgxMDI0MDUzNDIyMTEzNzMyO
Warning: Q%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT9BhJfQrBULLiNNXWfLQjhog3T8szmLRvMUEfWqE-cQIQ&
Warning: oe=6266DFF7&_nc_sid=83d603: File name too long
  0  175k    0  1492    0     0   1406      0  0:02:07  0:00:01  0:02:06  1426
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

Depending on your system, perhaps this succeeded, but the filename wasn't what you wanted. This is trying to include the entire query string in the filename.

This seems about all you can do with curl as it stands. You either have to determine the filename yourself (such as with sed) and pass it with the `-o` option, or you need to use something other than curl.

I note that [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/) handles this like you'd hope. Perhaps you could use it instead of curl?

```
$ http --download 'https://instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=gKuf2i9Vj5MAX-prxmR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjgxMDI0MDUzNDIyMTEzNzMyOQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT9BhJfQrBULLiNNXWfLQjhog3T8szmLRvMUEfWqE-cQIQ&oe=6266DFF7&_nc_sid=83d603'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600, no-transform
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 179351
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 12:25:45 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Apr 2022 06:31:15 GMT
X-FB-Server-Cluster-Forwarded: syd2c01
X-Frame-Options: DENY
content-digest: adler32=3445021316
cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin
timing-allow-origin: *
x-haystack-needlechecksum: 1987900843
x-needle-checksum: 1431545784

Downloading 175.15 kB to "277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg"
Done. 175.15 kB in 1.08534s (161.38 kB/s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You curl command is missing quote, it should be:

curl -o a.jpg 'https://instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.fwlg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=gKuf2i9Vj5MAX-prxmR&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=MjgxMDI0MDUzNDIyMTEzNzMyOQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT9BhJfQrBULLiNNXWfLQjhog3T8szmLRvMUEfWqE-cQIQ&oe=6266DFF7&_nc_sid=83d603'

Comment: I dont want the file name to be `a.jpg` ... it needs to be whatever is in the url ie `277901819_162489612877754_7456098591865793913_n.jpg` which will not always be a `jpg` can be other extensions as well

Comment: Maybe there is no such options for wget and curl. You may write a script to do this.